# How to provide 'data-toggle="modal"' from code behind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Hyperlink my code, for which I want to provide "`data-toggle`"

```
HyperLink lnk = new HyperLink();
lnk.NavigateUrl = "somelink";
lnk.?? here I don't know how to give "data-toggle"
```

So that at the end I can have a link in the page as below:

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="somelink"></a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Attributes` collection, you can find more in [How to: Set HTML Attributes for Controls in ASP.NET Web Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f.aspx)

```
lnk.Attributes["data-toggle"] = "modal";
```